# Make json.dumps output unicode characters properly in Python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to encode a UTF8 string. Using PHP's `json_encode()`, `…` (U+2026) becomes `\u2026`. However, using Python's `json.dumps()`, it becomes `\u00e2\u20ac\u00a6`. How do I convert this to `\u2026` in Python?

Here's the entire program:

```
import nltk
import json

file=open('pos_tag.txt','r')
tags=nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(file.read()))

print(json.dumps(tags,separators=(',',':')))
```

Comment: Can you please include complete code fragments of what you are trying to do, such as how you might be doing this in the Python shell.

Comment: I've attached the entire program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in `file.open()`. I was able to fix it using the codecs module:

```
import nltk
import json
import codecs

file=codecs.open('pos_tag.txt','r','utf-8')
tags=nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(file.read()))

print(json.dumps(tags,separators=(',',':')))
```